# Alpha numeric sequence generator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How can I generate Alphanumeric ID efficiently like 
Rxt-AA0001 
Rxt-AA0002 
Rxt-AA0003 
.. 
.. 
Rxt-AA9999 
Rxt-AB0001 
Rxt-AB0002

With this

```
public class UserIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
 
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;
 
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;
 
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }
 
    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
                params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
                params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
 
}
```

here is my user id in model

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_seq_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "user_seq_generator", strategy = "user.util.UserIdGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = UserIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = UserIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "RxT-AA"),
            @Parameter(name = UserIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%04d") })
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String Id;
```

I am able to generate Alpha numeric id but I am not sure how can I increment characters

Comment: and an array with all the letters, and increment the index of the array

Answer (score 1):

Generally when creating IDs it is best practice to not increment them. This makes them insecure. This video contains a good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

Java has a build in UUID class for generating ids.
This is the javadoc for it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite simply - see the class below.

However depends on the purpose it might be more beneficial to use the UUID, as suggested by @Someone

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AlphaNumber {
    public static char[] ALPHA_NUMBER_CHARS = "0123ABC".toCharArray(); // add here your characters
    private int[] number = new int[32]; // here you control the maximum size of the number
    private int size = 0; // here we control the actual size of the number

    public AlphaNumber() {
        Arrays.fill(number,0);
    }

    public String inc() {
        for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {
            number[i]++;
            if (number[i] < ALPHA_NUMBER_CHARS.length) {
                break;
            }
            number[i]=0;
            size = Math.max(i+1,size);
        }
        return toString();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = size; i>=0; i--) {
            r.append(ALPHA_NUMBER_CHARS[number[i]]);
        }
        return new String(r);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlphaNumber a = new AlphaNumber();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(a.inc());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't asked correctly see there i have numerals values incremented all i need is to increment AA to AB when number reaches 9999 and that will be saved in data base now my current idea is to store all the id's in a HashMap then for every new user i generate id and check if it is already used and if number goes higher then 9999 change alphabets and check again of course i know UUID but this is the requirement

Comment: @SunnyKumar you have to spill the beans ... tell us what are your requirements.

I have a feeling that you might need to go one more level down and implement that as a store proc. if you keep that on the hibernate layer it might not work. How many application servers do you have? How are you going to keep them in sync?

Comment: currently there is only one app server but future plan is to add more servers, but now that you mentioned i think store procedure might work i'll give it a try. And as I mentioned i need id in FIXED_ALPHA + VAR_ALPHA + VAR_NUMBER

Comment: add a second array like number[]. For example: numberDigits[], and process them in consecutive steps